# Live title goes into infinite loop

Tags: windows-phone-7

I use live title to launch a specific page:

Live tile in Home screen --launch-->  P1 after a task and goto --> P2 --> MainPage

When you click back button in MainPage the app won't exit instead it goes to P2 in a loop fashion.

Here is the code:

```
        try
        {
            ShellTile TileToFind = ShellTile.ActiveTiles.FirstOrDefault(x => x.NavigationUri.ToString().Contains("PageTakePic.xaml"));

            if (TileToFind == null)
            {

                StandardTileData NewTileData = new StandardTileData
                {

                    //BackgroundImage = new Uri("Red.jpg", UriKind.Relative),
                    //--front tile
                    Title = "Take Pic",
                    //Count = 12,

                    BackTitle = "Quick Access",
                    //--40 char
                    BackContent = "Take Pic",
                    //BackBackgroundImage = new Uri("Blue.jpg", UriKind.Relative)
                };

                // Create the Tile and pin it to Start. This will cause a navigation to Start and a deactivation of our application.
                ShellTile.Create(new Uri("/PageTakePic.xaml", UriKind.Relative), NewTileData);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("A live title created for this service already.");
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Try again. Error encountered: " + ex.Message);
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        }
```

---

Update:

Live tile in Home screen --launch--> P1 (PageTakePic.xaml) --> P2 --> MainPage

using below method not working In MainPage. It still goes into a loop:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

    NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
}
```

Comment: Seems like the problem would be elsewhere.. Are there any places on your MainPage where you navigate to PageTakePic? I'd guess somewhere along the way you're setting some variable which you use to determine you should navigate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a common issue to consider with Deep Links from Live Tiles in Mango. What you need to do is remove the BackStack entries when you hit your Main Page so that hitting the back button will exit the app.

Here is a snippet that may help:

```
    void ClearBackStack()
    {
        while (NavigationService.CanGoBack)
        {
            NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have updated with your method. It still goes back into loop.

Comment: Hmmm you might try RootFrame.RemoveBackEntry, or it may be something else.

Comment: Also in your question update you show you are just calling RemoveBackEntry once, but you need to call it in a loop like in this ClearBackStack function I posted. Maybe just copy and paste the ClearBackStack function in and call it and see if that fixes it?

Comment: Thank you. You are right. place in in the NavigatedTo event. It works as per your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

If you handle errors by navigating to home page like in your example:

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

Then it is possible that at some point when you navigate back - you get an error and navigate to MainPage instead, so your live tile gets you to PageTakePic, then when you press back - navigation fails and you navigate forward instead to MainPage. Then the back button gets you back to PageTakePic and so on...

Comment: yes, I use your navigation method in P2. when I MainPage, I need to exit the app by pressing backkey button but it goes back to P2 in a loop. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: I'd never done deep linking tiles, but I bet there are samples that do that and show how it's done. I would try putting a breakpoint (F9) on all lines in the app that call Navigate or GoBack methods and I am almost sure you will find one of them being called unexpectedly. Then you can check the stack to see why.